# Trying to install PyCrypto on Ubuntu via Buildout, src/config.h: No such file or directory

Tags: python, ubuntu, pycrypto

I'm trying to install PyCrypto on an Ubuntu instance via Buildout (via easy_install) and I'm getting the following error:

```
Getting distribution for 'pycrypto>=1.9'.
Running easy_install:
/usr/bin/python "-S" "-c" "import sys,os;p = sys.path[:];import site;sys.path[:] = p;    [sys.modules.pop(k) for k, v in sys.modules.items() if hasattr(v, '__path__') and len(v.__path__)==1 and not os.path.exists(os.path.join(v.__path__[0],'__init__.py'))];from setuptools.command.easy_install import main;main()" "-mUNxd" "/opt/rocktech/buildout/cache/eggs/tmppKIfK7" "-Z" "/opt/rocktech/buildout/cache/download/dist/pycrypto-2.4.tar.gz"
path=/opt/rocktech/buildout/cache/eggs/setuptools-0.6c12dev_r88846-py2.6.egg

Processing pycrypto-2.4.tar.gz
Running pycrypto-2.4/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-dD_8Pu/pycrypto-    2.4/egg-dist-tmp-_d3xDl
error: Setup script exited with error: src/config.h: No such file or directory
An error occurred when trying to install pycrypto 2.4. Look above this message for any     errors that were output by easy_install.
While:
  Installing django.
  Getting distribution for 'pycrypto>=1.9'.
Error: Couldn't install: pycrypto 2.4
```

Any idea on what's causing this?

Notably, I had the same issue locally on Snow Leopard and I was able to fix it by downloading the code directly and running `python manage.py build` and `python manage.py install` by hand. I want to avoid that here because I'm deploying to a dozen servers.

Comment: You might try asking on serverfault...

Comment: someone else with the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897486/missing-src-config-h-when-trying-to-install-pycrypto-via-easy-install

Answer (score 2):

Even with the newest pycrypto I keep having this problem, so I just run `./configure` and the src/config.h is created, so now just run pip or, easy_install or, setup.py...

Answer (score 1):

It appears this is an open issue. The workaround is to use pip instead or stick to PyCrypto 2.3. https://bugs.launchpad.net/pycrypto/+bug/881130

EDIT: This bug was fixed in PyCrypto 2.4.1.

Answer (score 1):

You can also download pycrypto-2.4.tar.gz unpack it and run (as root):

```
./configure
python setup.py install
```

After that pycrypto will be installed into /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Crypto. I tested it on 'easy_install pysnmp'.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an update, PyCrypto has since resolved this issue as you can see from the ticket being marked "Fix Resolved": https://bugs.launchpad.net/pycrypto/+bug/881130. Just an FYI, in case someone comes across this later. This "should" be a non-issue now.